# Setting a TextView with a database value

Tags: java, android

What is the best practice to set text for a textview with a given string and some value from my database?

**My MainActivity**:

```
MyModel model;

TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
title.setText("Username: ", model.getName());
```

**My Model**

```
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

I couldn't find a solution so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) has several signatures, but the one you need is:

> public final void setText (CharSequence text)

So you could do:

```
title.setText("Username: " + model.getName());
```

but **AS** usually complains in these cases that you should avoid concatenating strings inside `setText()`, 
so what you can do is:

```
String str = "Username: " + model.getName();
title.setText(str);
```

Also you should consider to store literal values like `"Username: "` in resources like:

```
<string name="username">Username:</string>
```

and use it like this:

```
String str = getResources().getString(R.string.username) + model.getName();
title.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating getters and setters are a good practice, which you can automatically generate in Android Studio after defining the variables for the model. Other than that I dont know why in your `getName()` your method wants to return a long and you are actually returning a string. Change `long` to `String`

**like this :**

```
  public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything others have said about concatenating strings outside of the setText method is valid. As far as placement in the Activity or Fragment (*I'm using a Fragment in this example*), I use the follow conventions:

**Declare my class fields in the class body outside of my methods (*for class-wide access*)**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView titleView;

    public MyFragment() {
    //Constructor
    }
    // and so on ...
}
```

**Then, find my TextView reference once the Fragment is inflated, and if needed immediately, set its value**

```
// ...
@override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, container, false);

    titleView = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    String titleStr = "Username: " + model.getName();
    titleView.setText(titleStr);

    return view;
}
// ...
```

If I'm expecting the database value in question to change (*for example the user updating their username in settings*) then I may also wish to make use of certain lifecycle methods that trigger when a Fragment (*or Activity*) resumes after being suspended, but is not completely rebuilt.

```
// ...
@override
public void onResume() {

    titleStr = "Username: " + model.getName();
    titleView.setText(titleStr);

}
// ...
```

Here's a link regarding the [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) if you're not familiar with it, and here's a good rundown on [Fragments](https://www.journaldev.com/9266/android-fragment-lifecycle). Hope this helps.